How do you construct these level curves and orientations? (Hatcher, Algebraic Topology)
Some of Hatchers notation:
$\varphi \in \Delta^0 (X ; G)$ and $\psi \in \Delta^1 (X ; G)$. Also, $\delta : \Delta^k (X ; G) \rightarrow \Delta^{k+1}(X; G)$. $C_\psi$ is a collection of disjoint curves that cross the 1-skeleton transversely.
From Hatcher page 189 on cohomolgy:

When $G = \mathbb{Z}$ we can refine this construction by building $C_{\psi}$ from a number of arcs in each 2-simplex, each arc having a transverse orientation, the orientation which agrees or disagrees with the orientation of each edge according to the sign of the value of $\psi$ on the edge, as in the figure at the right [the figure below]. The resulting collection $C_{\psi}$ of disjoint curves in $X$ can be thought of as something like level curves for a function $\varphi$ with $\delta \varphi = \psi$, if such a function exists. The value of $\varphi$ changes by 1 each time a curve of $C_{\psi}$ is crossed.


I want a detailed explanation that a toddler could follow to orient these arcs and (when possible) construct level curves:
I was able to understand his easier example on page 188, but this one stumps me. There's a lot to digest that I feel Hatcher doesn't talk enough about. I feel there's a great geometric intuition in here, but I need a more thorough explanation of how we're constructing these oriented arcs and under certain circumstances (exactness?) constructing level curves. I wrote out some of my questions in the box below, but feel free to skip reading it; I principally just need a better and more thorough explanation of what Hatcher consistently wants you to do.

Various thoughts:
I've thought about this passage and picture for over an hour, and I still have no idea what sort of consistent procedure you are supposed to do to orient these arcs, and even what an orientation means. Are we orienting with those little arrows in the middle by "concave side or convex side", or "towards vertex or away from vertex"? What are we using to judge the orientation? Do we go counterclockwise and make it "towards vertex" or "away from vertex" if the difference is positive or negative? How are we computing this difference between edges anyhow? Are we reading the numbers off the figure? Or do we, for instance, treat $v_2$ in the first figure as being the orientation of the triangle: do we set it to $v_0$ and do the usual alternating sum of sides before calculating the difference across these arcs?


To improve this question, please add some basic context for those not having Hatcher in front of them. For example, is $\psi$ a generic $1$-cocycle? And $\varphi$ a generic $0$-cochain? As I remember, this should be it, but it would be good to set the scene

@FShrike Done (added above page excerpt).

Briefly, to describe simplicial-cohomology groups: $$H^i(X,G) := ker(\delta_{i})/Im(\delta_{i-1}).$$
These are constructed from the collection of maps (p.189):
$$\delta_i: \Delta^i(X,G)\to \Delta^{i+1}(X,G)$$
$$\color{blue}{\big(\delta_i\varphi\big)([v_0,...,v_{i+1}]):= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i+1}(-1)^j\varphi\big([v_0,...,\hat{v_j},...,v_{i+1}]\big)}.$$
where the sets of functions:
$$\Delta^i(X,G):= \big\{\varphi:\{[v_{0},...,v_{i}]\in X\}\to G\big\},$$
inherit abelian group structure from the image operations in $G$ (making the quotient a group).

With that out of the way, it seems Hatcher wants to illustrate the nuances of exactness at a node in the chain complex:
$$...\to \Delta^{i-1}\xrightarrow{\delta_{i-1}}\Delta^i\xrightarrow{\delta_i} \Delta^{i+1}\to ...$$
(exactness happens when $ker(\delta_i) = Im(\delta_{i-1})$). But I think he goes off the rails too far with, [paraphrasing] "what does it mean geometrically for $\varphi\in ker(\delta_i)$ or $\varphi\in Im(\delta_{i-1})$".


Now we've arrived at the problem in (p.188-199). Instantiate the above with $X$ being a 2D simplicial complex and $G := \{\mathbb{Z}_2,+,0\}$ or $\{\mathbb{Z},+,0\}$.
Thus our functions in $\Delta^1$ in the first case look like $\varphi:\{[v_0,v_1]\}\to \{0,1\}$, etc. 
Starting at any edge where $Im(\varphi) = 1$, we can draw a curve through the surface that crosses other edges with $Im(\varphi) = 1$ and doesn't cross with $Im(\varphi) = 0$ (see the figure on p.188).
From here, we see the blue equation come into play to designate:
$$\delta_1\varphi ([v_0,v_1,v_2]):= \varphi([v_1,v_2])-\varphi([v_0,v_2])+\varphi([v_0,v_1]) = 0$$
when $\varphi$ takes the image of $1$ on 2 of the edges with opposing orientations or not all.
And this gets generalized. So instead suppose on a given edge, $\varphi$ takes an integer image $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then we can assume that edge has crossings from $|n|$ curves, each with orientation assigned opposite of the edge's if $sgn(n)=-1$ or concurrent if $sgn(n) = 1$ (see '-3' on the right figure on p.189). If $\delta_1\varphi \equiv 0$, it is possible to make all the connections between edges. Otherwise, $\varphi$ might have images that we can't match up (say if the '-3' was a '-4').

$\underline{\text{Edit:}}$ @FShrike: If $X$ is an arbitrary simplicial complex, with $G = \mathbb{\{Z,+,0\}},$ then we can assert existence of such collections of lines with $\delta_1\varphi \equiv 0$. Though this is beyond the scope of the problem.

There remains a question about "then we can assume the edge has crossings from $|n|$ curves". The op would want to construct these, know if that's possible for a general simplicial complex.
